European raunchy movie, two guys hitchhiking or camping meet woman
This movie can't be more than 2-3 years old, maybe last year.
It's foreign (to USA): I believe either German or Austrian, but can't be sure. Definitely European.

In the trailer, two young guys are either hitchhiking or camping.
They need a place to the stay for the night; a young woman with a house invites them in.

One of the fellows starts having sex with her.
During intercourse, he chastises his companion: "She's letting us stay here, you should do something for her, it's only polite".
He responds, annoyed: "What do you want me to do?"
First fellow: "Stick a finger up her arse."
Semi-incredulous: "She'll like that?"
As he's still working away, exasperated: "Of course! Everyone likes that"

It was really vulgar, and of course even funnier to me because it was all subtitled.
Bonus clue: I'm pretty sure the New Yorker reviewed it the week it came out.

I think this is Danish film Klown.
Here is the Red Band trailer on YouTube.

That was it, thanks! New Yorker review: http://www.newyorker.com/arts/reviews/film/klown_norgaard
